# Do I need to include jQuery core alongside jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it necessary to include the core of jQuery, or is the mobile framework sufficient alone?
From what I`ve tried, I concluded that both files are necessary, but I would like to be sure on this issue.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[The docs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages/) give you all the information you need to know:

> A jQuery Mobile site must start with an HTML5 'doctype' to take full advantage of all of the framework's features. (Older devices with browsers that don't understand HTML5 will safely ignore the 'doctype' and various custom attributes.) In the 'head', **references to jQuery, jQuery Mobile and the mobile theme CSS** are all required to start things off.

In short, yes, jQuery core *is* required.

Answer (score 5):

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.js

Based on the code, it doesn't redefine jQuery but extends it so yes, you need the core.

```
(function( jQuery, window, undefined ) {

})( jQuery, this );
```

It passes the jQuery object when defining `jQuery.mobile`. See the [demo](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a1/) which includes core before mobile.