# jQuery Mobile vs regular jQuery

Tags: jquery

I read this thread
[jQuery vs jQuery Mobile vs jQuery UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636388/jquery-vs-jquery-mobile-vs-jquery-ui)

but still confused. Is jQuery mobile interchangeable with desktop jQuery?

Can jQuery mobile be used for desktop development?
and 
Can you use regular jQuery for mobile development?

Other than better touch support , what other advantages does jQuery Mobile offer?

Comment: jQuery Mobile is a bit of a misnomer. Unlike jQuery, which is just a JavaScript library, jQuery Mobile is something of a development framework - it comes with required HTML structure, CSS, themes, images, etc.

Comment: What would you call it then if you could name it? I can't think of another name that better describes it off hand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let me help explain this a little bit.

jQuery is the basic foundation for jQuery Mobile and jQueryUI, sort of like the basement is for the rest of a house. jQuery itself has many great tools to manipulate a webpage and add interactivity to a page, as well as many other fancy features that can't be accomplished by HTML and CSS alone. Here is their site for all of the different things that can be done with jQuery alone: http://api.jquery.com/.

jQueryUI is built on top of jQuery, much like how the first level of a house is built on top of a basement. jQuery UI contains a series of pre-built, interactive widgets which can be easily integrated into a website. Keep in mind that all of jQuery UI was built using simply jQuery, JavaScript, and CSS. It is possible (and really easy) to replicate these widgets yourself using only jQuery. These guys were just nice enough to write them for you. :) Here is a site where you can check out all of their widgets: http://jqueryui.com/demos/.

Last we come to jQuery Mobile. This is also built on top of jQuery, but not on top of jQuery UI. Using my previous analogies, you can think of it as a garage. It's not on top of a first floor, but it sits right beside it, with a different purpose than the main living space of a house. jQuery Mobile is like a combination of jQuery and a lightweight, altered version of jQuery UI, optimized for use on mobile devices. In essence, it is a framework of code and widgets that add application-like features and widgets to a webpage for mobile use. You can demo jQuery Mobile right here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.2/, or you can quickly build your own jQuery Mobile page using this drag and drop tool: http://codiqa.com/.

Hope that was helpful in distinguishing between them.

Comment: @spryno724, so what does this mean in terms of cross-platform development. Is it reasonable to make a website that works on both desktops/laptops and mobile phones with the same libraries? Like, in building a website (once), should it refer to both jquery mobile and jquery? or maybe, have an if-condition that refers to jquery mobile when the client device is small, and regular jquery.js otherwise?

Answer (score 4):

jQuery is a library in which jQuery Mobile and jQuery UI rely upon.

jQuery Mobile is designed for the touch and smaller screen experience.

jQuery UI is designed for the standard screen experience sans touch.

jQuery in itself is perfectly fine to use it for mobile or non-mobile. Its just jQuery Mobile and jQuery UI have already done a nice job of building that for you as they are based on jQuery itself.

I'm not sure what more needs to be said.

Comment: So to use jQuery Mobile you need to include regular jQuery as well? (since you say jQuery Mobile and UI rely upon jQuery). I see that the jQuery Mobile JS file is just 24 KB long (minified), whereas regular jQuery is 90+ KB (min too). So I suppose jQ Mobile can't contain all the functionality that jQ has.

Comment: @OMA jQuery Mobile is a separate code base than jQuery but relies upon it. As a developer this makes complete sense to separate them.