# Issues linking JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am currently making a website for my company, and have come across this issue while linking JQuery mobile. Before I linked JQuery mobile, everything was fine and all the elements were in order. However, once I linked JQuery mobile text has appeared at the bottom of the page saying 'Loading'. Nothing happens to the presentational elements at all, and nothing is put out of place, but this loading can be seen at the bottom of the webpage. I have never experienced this before and cannot find anything online, so any help would be appreciated. I am also using Bootstrap 3.

My code linking the scripts:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet">
```

Images of the normal page:

[image: normal image]

Problem page:

[image: problem image]

Comment: You have a conflict but it's hard to tell with what without knowing more or seeing it live.  Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047798/jquery-mobile-vs-regular-jquery

Comment: What do you see for the CSS if you right click on the 'Loading' and inspect element?

Comment: All the CSS styles appear to be coming from the Bootstrap link, but even after removing the link it remains there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the JQuery Mobile CSS file as well.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
```

Adding that to your page head element after your JQuery Mobile js reference should fix things for you.