# JQuery Mobile Menu (toggle) issue

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am continuing my quest using JQuery mobile and I have ran into a new problem.
I created a small JQuery slide menu that utilizes JQuery *toggle*.

```
             $( "#TestMenu" ).toggle( "slow", function() {});
```

What happens is that the entire script runs fine. UNTIL,, I click on a link and load a page. Even though the page has the same content.

When I press F5 the menu works fine again.
I do know that with Jquery mobile something has done with the loading. I presume therefore that this is the issue.

But how to get around this. I do not know.

I created a small test case to isolate the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <title>Test &amp; Go</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1080, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
        <link href="interface/test/mobile.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
            ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
            ///######## FUNCTION TO LOAD ALL QUICKHANDLING OPTIONS
            ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
            ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
            function TestAndGoFunctions(){
                ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
                ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
                ///######## HANDLING : CHANGE THE PAYMENT
                ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
                ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
                $("body").on("click", "#TestMenuButton", function() {
                    ///######## TOGGLE THE DISPLAY STATE OF THE MENU
                     $( "#TestMenu" ).toggle( "slow", function() {});
                });
            }


            $(document).ready(function() {
                ///######## LOAD THE Test AND GO FUNCTIONALITY
                TestAndGoFunctions();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="TestMenuButton"></div>
            <div id="TestMenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="?page=start">Start</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?page=actions">Actions</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <div id="testBlock">
            VARIABLE = <?php echo @$_GET['page']; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to make a JSfiddle link.. But that does not work a 100% because it does not want to reload my page so I cannot show the error there. Despite that here is the link:

https://jsfiddle.net/ferencik/xucrhvhr/

I have edited the jquery code in an attempt to autoload the content. But no success yet.

Below my code :

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
        ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
        ///######## FUNCTION TO LOAD ALL QUICKHANDLING OPTIONS
        ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
        ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
        function TestAndGoFunctions(){
            ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
            ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
            ///######## HANDLING : CHANGE THE PAYMENT
            ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
            ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
            $("body").on("click", "#TestMenuButton", function() {
                ///######## TOGGLE THE DISPLAY STATE OF THE MENU
                $( "#TestMenu" ).toggle( "slow", function() {});
            });
        }

       $(document).on("pageshow", function( event ) {
           TestAndGoFunctions();           
       });

        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
            ///######## LOAD THE Test AND GO FUNCTIONALITY
            ///TestAndGoFunctions();
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            ///######## LOAD THE Test AND GO FUNCTIONALITY
            ///TestAndGoFunctions();
        });


        function TestClick(){
            $( "#TestMenu" ).toggle( "slow", function() {});
            alert("HI!!");
        }

        </script>
```

I hope that anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

This is because jquery mobile loads new pages via ajax, so basically the ready function does not get 'loaded again'.

Read this: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html
And read this: [Difference between jQuery and jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391856/difference-between-jquery-and-jquery-mobile)

Comment: Thanks!! Now I should fiddle out how to reload the function after the call.