# How to remove jquery mobile style but keep the functionality?

Tags: jquery

I added ***data-role="none"*** in checkbox control and removed the style successfully.

However, I still want to use jQuery to manipulate it and following error raised. It occurs when ***refresh*** method is called.

**Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'**

May I know if there is way to keep functionality of jQuery when remove the style?

Thank you for help.

Comment: [Here](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-remove-jquery-mobile-styling/) you can find three different solutions for removing the styling. The `data-role="none"` will make jquery ignore the element, so I don't think you can keep the functionality. Try one of the other solutions.

Comment: thanks, I am still trying with 2 other solutions but not success yet. The style still exists. Checking if I am wrong in syntax or if I done anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just use regular jquery. You can download it at https://jquery.com/download/ or you can import it into your code using.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This way you'll get all the goodness of jquery without it changing your style. You can learn about the different jquery's and what they do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10392109/4852388).

Comment: thanks for that but in this project, the stakeholders request that the rest of controls still having the jQuery mobile style except checkbox.