# Possible to use jQuery mobile WITHOUT the AJAX - use styles only?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mobile

I know there's a jQuery Mobile download-customizer, but I can't figure out which options I need to check. It seems like the styles for input elements are tied to the AJAX functionality?

ALL I WANT - is the styles for buttons, menus, sliders, etc. I just want them to look clean and cool, they don't need to asynchronously download anything.

WHAT I'M INADVERTENTLY GETTING - is all the AJAX stuff, that causes these errors on page load:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load...
```

I've also tried including these types of snippets:

```
// disable jQuery mobile AJAX stuff
$(document).live("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.ajaxFormsEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
});
```

So no matter what I've tried, I cannot get cool looking sliders and buttons without also getting these AJAX errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/ and http://jquery.com/ have different basic functions and in this respect I believe you are attempting to only use the UI portion

check this response out

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6636467/1815624

  JavaScript and the XMLHttpRequest object provide a method for exchanging data asynchronously between browser and server to avoid full page reloads.*

*Ajax (programming), http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ajax_(programming)&oldid=527356893 (last visited Dec. 10, 2012).

simplistic example:
Client "Hey server I need page B"
Server "What do you have now?"
Client "Page A"
Server "Then you only need..."

Comment: thanks! I think you're right, I don't need to use jQuery Mobile, just the UI

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [theme roller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php)? Also check out [ratchet](http://maker.github.com/ratchet/) for mobile styles.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the theme roller as suggested and review the docs page from your target device:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/

additionally you can try the alpha tool found here:

- http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

but as noted on that page currently

> Please note that the jQuery Mobile Download Builder is still in alpha, and as such should not be used on production websites.

I may be wrong but I believe the slider needs Ajax functionality to work properly... If you want to optimize the code for speed consider using Google's mirrors for loading the library...this will generally access a cached copy on the devices decreasing the bandwidth load for a given page.

- https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=fr

Comment: doesn't theme roller still require the basic jQuery mobile functionality? Which would still include the AJAX stuff?