# jQuery Get function wont work when on a real mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I have been working on an app that collects a csv file from dropbox and then display's it. Since I am using phonegap I have been developing and testing with a browser, Firefox to more precise. At the end of the day I loaded it on to my HTC tablet with android 3.2.1 and it just didn't work. Here's the code currently used:

```
$.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53792213/App/David.csv', function(data) {
        alert('Success');
        // Do stuff
    })
    .fail(function() { alert('error'); });
```

This code works absolutely fine in Firefox and on an android emulator with android 4.2.2. But not on the real physical device.

I simply cannot work it out. No errors are given, and the fail function is never called. Both alert's I have added don't fire.

It is extremely frustrating as I don't have access to remote debugging, and I can't debug on the desktop as it works fine on the desktop.

I am using jquery 2.0.2 along with jquery mobile 1.3.1

I'd appreciate even the slightest clue as to what is going on.

EDIT: In order to find out about the error, now that it is infact throwing an error I modified my statement to this:

```
$.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53792213/App/David.csv', function(data) {
        alert('Success');
        // Do stuff
    })    
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("An AJAX error occured: " + textStatus + "\nError: " + errorThrown);
        });
```

However this is the error it returns:

```
An AJAX error occured: error
Error:
```

A blank error message? Either I'm doing something wrong or javascript wants to kill me slowly.

EDIT 2:

After doing some experiments I have discovered more strange behaviour. If I add the get() function directly into my deviceReady function, as in it will get fired when the app is loaded and ready to go, it works perfectly.

But (and this is what has been happening) if I bind a click jquery event in the device ready function, and then call the get function inside it, it doesnt work. Here have a look at this:

```
var App = {

// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
onDeviceReady: function() {
    //This does work
    $.get('http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53792213/App/DavidColson.csv', function(data) {
        alert('Success');
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("An AJAX error occured: " + textStatus + "\nError: " + errorThrown);
     });
    $("#Button").bind("click", function(event) {
        alert("Hello");
        //This does not work       
        $.get('http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53792213/App/DavidColson.csv', function(data) {
            alert('Success');
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("An AJAX error occured: " + textStatus + "\nError: " + errorThrown);
        });
    });
},
```

};

In the above situation the hello alert fires, but not the success alert, instead I get a blank ajax error. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI .error() is deprecated in favour of .fail()

Comment: Also, since you're requesting an asset using https, if your page wasn't served from the same server using https (the dropbox domain) then a potential source of the error is you violating the same origin policy in your browser.

Comment: How do I fix that? It's not actually a browser as such but a web view on android. I hoping there is a way to fix that. Or some alternative way of transfering files to the app

Comment: Apparently cross domain is disabled on phonegap. So that cannot be the problem

Comment: You might have to whitelist the domain according to the phonegap docs here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: I have whitelisted https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com, to no avail. Thanks for the suggestion though. It was actually set to whitelist everything, so it was never the problem :(

Comment: There are a few other settings inside jQuery and jQuery mobile that control cross domain requests. See http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html to check if `$.support.cors` and `$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages` need to be set.

Comment: I have set allowCrossDomainPages to true and confirmed that cors is true, still doesnt work though

Answer (score 0):

Why use both jQuery and jQuery mobile? Seems like you should just be able to use mobile and that the use of both libraries could be the cause of your issues through a conflict.

You could try adding a call to [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to resolve this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // This takes out the jQuery variable '$' from the global scope
  $.noConflict();

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53792213/App/David.csv',function(data)  
    {
       alert('Success');
    }).fail(function() { alert('error'); });
  });

  //rest of your normal jQuery that uses the $. here

</script>
```

**EDIT**: Looks like [jQuery mobile isn't compatible with jQuery 2](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-2-0-0-compatibility) yet. Try referencing jQuery 1.9.1 instead and see if that works.

Comment: I tried removing jquery and having just mobile, but then the app has a heart attack and nothing diplay's correctly, gets an error and then crashes. Besides which you do apparently need to include jquery core http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119672/do-i-need-to-include-jquery-core-alongside-jquery-mobile

Comment: Did you try the noConflict function?

Comment: See my edit. jQuery mobile isn't compatible with jQuery 2 according to its documentation.

Comment: Well I'm getting somewhere, thank you. It's still not entirely working though but I am getting the 'error' alert being thrown. I can work of that.